# Taking screenshot then trying to save it in emulator gallery but it is not saving

Tags: android

Here is my code to take screen shot and save it in gallery.tried by debugging here screen is captured but not saving to gallery.

```
@Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Bitmap bitmap = takeScreenshot();
                saveBitmap(bitmap);
            }
```

making screenshot

```
protected Bitmap takeScreenshot() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View rootView = findViewById(android.R.id.content).getRootView();
    rootView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Screen captured", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return rootView.getDrawingCache();

}
```

Saving screen here

```
 protected void saveBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            File imagePath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    + "/screenshot.png");

            FileOutputStream fos;
            try {
                fos = new FileOutputStream(imagePath);
                bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
                fos.flush();
                fos.close();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Screen saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                Log.e("GREC", e.getMessage(), e);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("GREC", e.getMessage(), e);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Run your code in device please, it may be the problem of emulator, because emulator dont have physical SD Card.